# Tic Tac Toe function calls do not call functions in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a simple Tic Tac Toe and I managed to get it working but without react. Now I'm trying to refactor the code and make it work with React, but I can't.

The logic itself works, but the problem is that the functions (restart and makeMove) aren't being called upon pressing the tiles or clicking the restart button

TicTacToe.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './TicTacToe.css'

const TicTacToe = () => {
  const x = '10006';
  const o = '9898';

  const [firstPlayerMove, setFirstPlayerMove] = useState();
  const [gameWon, setGameWon] = useState();
  const [moves, setMoves] = useState();

  const showMsg = (msg) => {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = msg;
  }

  const setup = () => {
    setFirstPlayerMove(true);
    setGameWon(false);
    setMoves(0);
    showMsg("It's X's turn.");
  }

  const restart = () => {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("tile"), function(element) {
      element.innerHTML = "";
    });
    
    setup();
  }

  const makeMove = (tile) => {
    if(gameWon) {
      return false;
    }
    
    if(isValidMove(tile)) {
      setMoves(moves+1);
      
      if(firstPlayerMove) {
        tile.innerHTML = '&#' + x + ';';
      }
      else {
        tile.innerHTML = '&#' + o + ';';
      }
      
      if(checkWin()) {
        return true;
      }
      
      if(moves === 9) {
        showMsg("Draw.");
        return true;
      }
      
      setFirstPlayerMove(!firstPlayerMove);
      
      if(firstPlayerMove) {
        showMsg("It's X's turn.");
      }
      else {
        showMsg("It's O's turn.");
      }
    }
  }

  function isValidMove(tile) {
    return tile.innerHTML === '';
  }

  const checkWin = () => {
    var tiles = document.getElementsByClassName("tile");
    var xTiles = new Array(9);
    var oTiles = new Array(9);
    
    for(var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
      if(tiles[i].innerHTML === String.fromCharCode(x)) {
        xTiles[i] = 1;
      }
      
      if(tiles[i].innerHTML === String.fromCharCode(o)) {
        oTiles[i] = 1;
      }
    }
    
    if(hasWinningPattern(xTiles)) {
      showMsg("Player 1 (X) won.");
      return true;
    }
    
    if(hasWinningPattern(oTiles)) {
      showMsg("Player 2 (O) won.");
      return true;
    }
    
    return false;
  }

const hasWinningPattern = (tiles) => {
    var winningPatterns = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6]
    ];
    
    for(var i = 0; i < winningPatterns.length; i++) {
        var pattern = winningPatterns[i];
        
        var win = true;
        for(var j = 0; j < pattern.length; j++) {
            if(tiles[pattern[j]] !== 1) {
                win = false;
            }
        }
        
        if(win) {
            setGameWon(true);
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

  return (
    <div>
      <body onload={() => setup()}>
        <button onclick={() => restart()} class="start">Restart</button>
            <div class="board">
                <div class="row">
                    <div onclick={() => makeMove(this)} class="tile"></div>
                    <div onclick={() => makeMove(this)} class="tile"></div>
                    <div onclick={() => makeMove(this)} class="tile"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div onclick={() => makeMove(this)} class="tile"></div>
                    <div onclick={() => makeMove(this)} class="tile"></div>
                    <div onclick={() => makeMove(this)} class="tile"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div onclick={() => makeMove(this)} class="tile"></div>
                    <div onclick={() => makeMove(this)} class="tile"></div>
                    <div onclick={() => makeMove(this)} class="tile"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="msg" id="msg"></div>
      </body>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TicTacToe
```

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import TicTacToe from './TicTacToe';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TicTacToe/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to run through a few more tutorials on React. It's a bad idea to mix native DOM methods like `getElementsByClassName` with React because React has its own way of updating the DOM and they will clash. Maybe start with the [React documentation](beta.reactjs.org/).

Comment: Why do you have a `body` in your `div`?

Comment: @tkausl I wrote it like that in the original code. But won't removing it stop calling the setup() function?

Comment: Yes it will. Use react features instead, for example `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing because react has a bit different syntax for the **Handling Events** you will have to use `onClick` instead `onclick`.
[check this out](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

So changing it to *camelCase* will make it work.
Also instead following the `{() => makeMove(this)}` you can actually use `event.targent`.I hope it will get your work done.

Once your event starts working then you can go through your logic.

Comment: Thanks the restard button is now working but when clicking a tile I get an error in the console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerHTML')" on the line "return tile.innerHTML == '';"

Comment: Like I had mentioned earlier you can use ```event.target``` instead. Replace const ```makeMove = (tile) =>{} ``` with ```makeMove = (event) =>{}``` and now you can get ***tile** from ```event.targent```. You are using arrow function so at the onClick you just need to write the function name. Check that link I had mentioned for the function calling pattern.